# When should cooking, cuisine, and cookery be used?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

I have never really understood when the words *cooking*, *cuisine* and *cookery* should be used, and to what level they are synonymous. For example, in each example below, which could you use and why (or why not)?

> - Sicilian cuisine is based on seafood
> - the local cuisine is just fine, but their wine is terrible
> - my wife is much better than me at cooking pasta
> - Greg is more skilled than me in cookery
> - I am taking cooking classes after work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are not entirely interchangeable, but are used in an overlapping fashion by many.

I believe the more accurate uses would be as follows:

- ***cooking*** is the process of preparing food, particularly by the application of heat
- ***cookery*** is the group of methods and techniques, the art and science, particular to the process of cooking
- ***cuisine*** is the type and style of *cooking* and *food* particular to a location or culture

Comment: Could you please add supporting evidence for these claims (someone has asked a parallel question)? And isn't 'cuisine' broadened to include ' ... or an otherwise reasonably defined type / style' (eg 'seafood cuisine')?