# If “cooking show” is grammatical, why not “cooking book”?

Tags: grammar, etymology, food, transatlantic-differences

> I enjoy cooking,  and I've been told I'm  quite a good cook. I have several  cookery books <sup>**1**</sup> at home, mostly on Italian and British  cooking, but not one is written by a famous cookery writer <sup>**2**</sup>. I've never taken a cookery class <sup>**3**</sup>  in my life, but I have learnt a lot from TV cooks such as Jamie Oliver, Nigel Slater and Delia Smith, and I'm an avid fan of their cookery shows <sup>**4**</sup>.

The term *cookery* in numbers 2, 3, and 4 can be substituted with *cooking* with no change in meaning, which suggests that the two terms are virtually interchangeable. In fact, ***cookery*** is  *[the skill or activity of preparing and cooking food](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cookery)*
while ***cooking*** is defined as [*the activity of preparing or cooking food*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cooking) by Cambridge Dictionaries.

Nevertheless, the best alternative for ***cookery book*** is the compound noun ***cookbook***. The instances of ***cooking book***, which Google Ngrams  turned up, were vanishingly rare, and mostly, false positives.

American English Ngram chart
[image]

British English Ngram chart
[image]

Since the 1970s the expression *food writer* has superseded that of *cookery writer*, but *cooking writer*, although rare, is still used. See [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=food%20writer%2C%20cookery%20writer%2C%20cooking%20writer&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfood%20writer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccookery%20writer%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccooking%20writer%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfood%20writer%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Ccookery%20writer%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Ccooking%20writer%3B%2Cc1)

> When a **cooking writer** pens his autobiography it is invariably written with a freshly baked, rosy glow. Tales of baking at their mother's knee is what is expected.
> <sub>*Toast: The Story of a Boy's Hunger* by Nigel Slater</sub>

The following graphs clearly illustrate the phenomenal boom of *cooking shows*, and *cookery programmes* in the last forty years or so.  The [BrEng](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cooking%20show%2Ccooking%20programme%2Ccookery%20show%2Ccookery%20programme&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccooking%20show%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccooking%20programme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccookery%20show%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccookery%20programme%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccooking%20show%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Ccooking%20programme%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Ccookery%20show%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Ccookery%20programme%3B%2Cc1) corpus demonstrates that both titles are commonly used,

[image]

whereas the [AmEng](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cooking+show%2Ccooking+program&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccooking%20show%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccooking%20program%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccooking%20show%3B%2Cc1%3B.t1%3B%2Ccooking%20program%3B%2Cc1) corpus displays a distinct preference for *cooking show*. The description *cookery show* barely makes a visible dent on the chart

[image]

To sum up, if *cooking show*, *cooking class*, *cooking skills*, and to a lesser extent, *cooking writer* are all acceptable, what is it about *cooking book* that makes it sound so ‘weird’?

**Questions**

1. **Why is the term *cookery* rarely used for TV shows and books in American English?**
2. **Although recipe books are about cooking, these publications are practically never referred to as *cooking books*. Is there a *grammatical* or *semantic* reason for this?**

Comment: Good question about *cooking shows* vs *cook books*. At a guess, *cooking books* sounds like shady accounting, while *cook shows* sounds like reality TV about chefs. I'm not sure why "cook *book*" doesn't similarly evoke the idea of chef memoirs. (In case you were wondering: I don't have enough of a handle on the *cookery* question to venture a comment about it.)

Comment: @Lawrence the expression "cooking the books" is an old coinage. But *cookery book*, and *cook book* (today's *cookbook*) are older.

Comment: Yes, of course. However, if we went by conventional usage, Your Ngram charts would suffice as an answer :) .

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22689/when-should-cooking-cuisine-and-cookery-be-used

Comment: You actually cook in a cooking show, but not in a book. Can *cook book* be interpreted as *cook's book*, a book cooks always have with them?

Comment: You might like this post: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/784/translating-cooking-terms-between-us-uk-au-ca-nz

Comment: @Jacinto ha! I think you're onto something there.

Comment: @Mari-LouA It takes a foreigner... :) But I'm afraid that's all I can contribute to the topic.

Comment: "...The book... 'To Serve Man'... IT'S A COOKBOOK!"

Comment: @Oldbag You're going to have to explain the punchline to me, old bean. It's gone completely over my ehead. My question is not why a cookbook is called what it is, but what etymological, semantic or grammatical reason is there for it *not* to be called a cooking book.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - The quote is from a Twilight Zone episode: Monsters from outer space land at the UN in New York and present Earth's political representatives with a book written in their own language. A language genius translates the title as, "To Serve Man".  The monsters promote their "goodwill" by offering free trips to their home planet. The snippet I offered is the last thing the translater yells to her friend as the flying saucer takes off - with him on it.  (It's a classic.) Back on topic: It's probably called a "cookbook" 'cause "cookbook" is catchy to the ear,

Comment: My immediate thought on reading this Q. was along the same lines as @Jacinto : the book is telling you how to *cook* / how to do *cookery* &mdash; the show is actually demonstrating *cooking* resulting in cooked products.  Also, a *cooking book* sounds as if *it* actually does the cooking!

Comment: Here's a literary example: the protagonist of Roald Dahl's 1959 short story ["Pig"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pig_(short_story)) is writing what he calls a **"cooking-book"**. Maybe he expresses himself a little strangely on account of being raised and home-schooled by an eccentric great aunt who "lived a strange isolated life all by herself in a tiny cottage high up on the slopes of the Blue Ridge Mountains, several miles from the nearest village."

Comment: It's not ungrammatical, but is unusual. There are plenty of phrases we could make that make sense but aren't usual: cuisine book, real crime (it's called true crime). Sometimes it's even factually wrong: Young Adult fiction isn't for young adults, but teens. Look not for perfect rationality in language, for thou shalt be disappointed.

Comment: Basically, the Supreme Court of English didn't rule on this until after "cookbook" was established law.  And when they did get around to looking at it, they pointed out that there's a big difference between "grammatical" and "idiomatic".

Comment: @HotLicks  Ha... I love your wit.  I know it's not entirely correct but this was written in 2016 when I was more naive. Please forgive the carelessness.

Answer (score 1):

To [cook](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cook) as a transitive verb has the following meaning among many others:

> To alter or falsify.

As a slang, it also means to *happen* as in "What's cooking?" which means "What's happening?"

To cook has some *negative connotations* especially when it comes to the financial sector or narcotics business.

To [cook the books](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/cook+the+books) means

> to keep false financial records for an organization

I suspect the reason why "cooking book" or "cook book" is not as popular as "cookbook" is the negative connotation of the verb to *cook* when it is placed before the noun *book* with a space. I don't think it is a grammatical issue. People have chosen to use "cookbook" as it sounds better.

As for "cooking show", as @Jacinto commented, I don't think it matters that much because the show is about cooking (action) or how to cook food.

Comment: There has to be a reason why *cook book*, which later became *cookbook*, is the accepted term, rather than "it sounds better" to native speakers. Of course it does, they've been hearing *cookbook* all their lives.

Comment: @Mari-LouA There has to be a reason why "underground" in the UK is "subway" in the U.S and MTR in Hong Kong and MRT in Singapore.

Comment: Yes, there usually is for these kinds of things. They don't happen overnight.

Comment: @Mari-LouA The only reason I see is the US doesn't like the UK in the same way Singapore doesn't like HK. One thing common in three of them is they were a former colony of Britain.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Do you think you can vote to delete this answer? I read it and it doesn't seem to add any value. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/145899/is-it-grammatically-correct-to-say-many-more-happy-returns-of-the-day/294798#294798

Answer (score 0):

Already mentioned is the meaning of "cooking the books," but my first reaction was a visual of book burnings--where people are literally cooking books. There does seem a meaning in "cookbook" of a "cook's book" or "how-to-cook book" layered into the present usage.

As for cookery, I think of a cookie factory when I read or hear it, but I believe it is just a word that isn't in favor (at least in the US)--which seems in-line with your charts.

Comment: "Cook the books" is dated 1630s, but the verb *cook* is much older than that, it dates back to Old English *coc*.

Comment: We're talking about present usage and I'm sure it has evolved--the charts used only go back to 1970 and 1900.