# Cooking classes vs Cookery classes

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, grammaticality, sentence, syntactic-analysis

By definition,

**Cooking**: *the practice or skill of preparing food by combining, mixing, and heating ingredients*

**Cookery**: *the practice or skill of preparing and cooking food*

So, which one of the following is correct and why?

- I am going for **cooking** classes, these days.
- I am going for **cookery** classes, these days.

P.S. I just want to know whether it is grammatically acceptable to say cookery classes or not. Also, before asking this question, I googled up cookery classes (based on my location) and mixed responses came up:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: In AmE and BrE, 'cookery' and 'cookery classes' are just not used. It may very well be the right thing to say in your local version.

Comment: related: [If a “cooking show” is grammatical, why not a “cooking book”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/328702/if-a-cooking-show-is-grammatical-why-not-a-cooking-book)

Comment: "Cookery" is a British English term, unused in the US except in some cooking shows on TV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is wholly reasonable and if you will excuse me for pointing it out, I attended not *cooking* but *cookery* classes in secondary school, albeit nearly 50 years ago.

As Mari-Lou A noted, there are no *cooking* but any number of *cookery* books.

Working in retail I've spoken to dozens if not hundreds of providers and hundreds if not thousands of users about *cooking* and *cookery* and I insist that their - the - normal usage for *classes* is *cookery*, not *cooking*.

A *cooking* class would mean one *being* cooked.

A *cookery* class means one *about* cooking.

Answer (score 0):

Cookery is a "British" term - mainly from England. It is never heard in the US except for the occasional English expats amongst us (who also, for example, call the garbage bin and/or the trash can a "dust bin").

Comment: Random House says "[chiefly British](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/cookery)" but [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cookery) doesn't qualify it and has examples from American publications (although one is written by a British-Indian but edited in the US).

Answer (score 0):

> By definition,
>
> Cooking: the practice or skill of preparing food by combining, mixing, and heating ingredients.

This is the error.

**Cooking** is not *"the practice or skill of preparing food by combining, mixing, and heating ingredients."*

**Cooking** is a gerund and it is ***"the action** of preparing food by combining, mixing, and heating ingredients.*

**Cookery** (noun) is *"the practice or skill of preparing food by combining, mixing, and heating ingredients."* and is applicable to the formation of {attributive noun + noun} phrases.

Comment: So one needs to take dancery lessons? The definition of 'cooking' you reject is given by Collins.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth You cannot hold me responsible for what others might make of Collins' entry any more than I can hold you responsible from not knowing the difference between an obsolete deverbal noun and a gerund.

Comment: The rectifiable fault is insufficient or no supporting references. // I've not changed my stance from seeing the Quirk et al gradience model of ing-forms from deverbal noun (eg painting/s: pluralises) to present participle as the best explanation. I posted on this many years ago.